# Finding closest pair of coordinates from a list

Tags: python

I am attempting to implement the solution to a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981502/select-the-closest-pair-from-a-list)

I have a pair of coordinates that I wish to find the closest associated pair of coordinates in a list of coordinates.

This can be achieved by finding the pair with the minimum distance between points:

```
dist = lambda s,d: (s[0]-d[0])**2+(s[1]-d[1])**2
```

I have a dictionary, origin:

```
{u'toid': u'osgb4000000029928750', u'point': [524511.405, 184846.794]}
```

I have another list containing pairs of coordinates, d_origins:

```
[(532163.5648939193, 181848.77608212957),(532449.8292416488, 181847.71793660522), (532200.2156880093, 182053.30247829395), (533794.6284605444, 181119.5631480558)]
```

I then attempt to find the match value by calling the dist lambda function:

```
match = min((origin[0]['point']),key=partial(dist,d_origins))
print origins, match
```

however, the output is:

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `min(d_origins, key=partial(dist, origin['point']))`?

Comment: Anyway, if you post an error, post your code and post the traceback.  The traceback is really important and usually contains the answer to your question.  The fact that you didn't include it indicates that you didn't read it closely as well.

Comment: Very true, Sven! I solved it by reading the trace carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min` function takes a list or iterable. Additionally the ordering can be specified by a function with one argument. That means the function maps an element to a value, which is then compared by the `min` function to find the minimum element.

```
match = min(d_origins, key=lambda p: dist(p, origin['point']))
```

The lambda expression wraps the `dist` function with two arguments to a function with one argument by providing one of the arguments. The new anonymous function compares a coordinate with the specific origin in the lambda expression. Then, the result of the `min` function is the closest coordinate to this origin.

Full example:

```
>>> dist = lambda s,d: (s[0]-d[0])**2+(s[1]-d[1])**2
>>> origin = {'toid': 'osgb4000000029928750', 'point': [524511.405, 184846.794]}
>>> d_origins = [(532163.5648939193, 181848.77608212957),(532449.8292416488, 181847.71793660522), (532200.2156880093, 182053.30247829395), (533794.6284605444, 181119.5631480558)]
>>> 
>>> match = min(d_origins, key=lambda p: dist(p, origin['point']))
>>> print(str(match))
(532200.2156880093, 182053.30247829395)
```